# C# - saving selected date from monthCalendar in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, monthcalendar

I'm making a calendar with C#. For this I use MonthCalendar (windows Forms).
I want to select a date on the calendar and add some text to that date (like an appointment). And then I want to save the date and the text in a dictionary.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace agenda
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

        //Selected only 1 date
        monthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 1;
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var geselecteerdeDatum = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString(); 

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<DateTime, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();
        dictionary.Add(geselecteerdeDatum, textBox1.Text);

        //show what is in the dictionary / print it in the console
        Console.WriteLine(geselecteerdeDatum);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<DateTime, string> kvp in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    public DateTime geselecteerdeDatum{ get; set; }
}
```

}

The form contains a MonthCalendar, a button and a text field.
When I run this, I'm able to save some text to the dictionary. But the date from the MonthCalendar won't save correctly to the dictionary. 
Everytime it looks like this:

```
  Key = 1-1-0001 00:00:00, Value = message
```

Does anybody know how I can get the selected date in the dictionary?

Comment: You have `var geselecteerdeDatum` in the DateSelected event.  That is going out of scope.  Remove the var and make sure your variable is declared at the form scope.

Comment: What do you mean with: make sure your variable is declared at the form scope?

Comment: Before your edit, I didn't see your geselecteerdeDatum variable anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with pasting my code and translating it to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dictionary.Add(geselecteerdeDatum, textBox1.Text);`
to `dictionary.Add(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart, textBox1.Text);`

And there is no need to set `MaxSelectionCount` more than once (you can do it in the form designer).

`var geselecteerdeDatum` creates a new string variable (local) which has nothing to do with your `DateTime geselecteerdeDatum`